# Odoo how domain attribute works?

Tags: view, odoo

I have a One2many relation in my odoo ' student .student'  model  that's it

```
result_ids = fields.One2many("schoolresults.detail", "student_id", "SchoolResults")
```

"schoolresults.detail" model has the following  Many2One relational fields

```
student_id = fields.Many2one("student.student", "Student", ondelete="cascade")
subject_id = fields.Many2one("schoolresults.subject", "Subject")
```

The problem is when adding the result ids field its possible to add some subject twice to the same student and with a different scores .
I tried to make sql_constrait 'UNIQUE (student_id, subject_id)' on schoolresults.detail 
Model  but it raises an error .
I don’t want the subject to appear on the selction field if it is already selected.
I think the answer is arround domain attribute,
this image may cover  my language faults.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so74o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should return a domain on onchange of your one2many field **result_ids**.
eg:

```
ids_list = []
@api.onchnage('result_ids')
def onchange_result_ids(self):
    for record in self.result_ids:
        if record.subject_id:
           ids_list.append(record.subject_id.id)

    return {'domain': {'subject_id': [('id', 'not in', ids_list)]}}
```